# How to log YOLOV4 Darknet into Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard, darknet, yolov4

I am using Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg?usp=sharing to train YOLOV4 custom detector. The repo used in the Colab is: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

I want the training results (Loss, mAP) to be displayed on Tensorboard. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its possible but you can use --mjpeg_port 8090 to stream the mAP plot to http. Which you can use in an iframe.